# pandas.read_csv moves column names over one

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am using the ALL.zip file located [here](http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do). My goal is to create a pandas DataFrame with it. However, if I run

`data=pd.read_csv(foo.csv)`

the column names do not match up. The first column has no name, and then the second column is labeled with the first, and the last column is a Series of NaN. So I tried

```
colnames=[list of colnames]
data=pd.read_csv(foo.csv, names=colnames, header=False)
```

which gave me the exact same thing, so I ran

```
data=pd.read_csv(foo.csv, names=colnames)
```

which lined the colnames up perfectly, but had the csv assigned column names(the first line in the csv document) perfectly aligned as the first row of data it. So I ran

```
data=data[1:]
```

which did the trick.

So I found a work around without solving the actual problem. I looked at the [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) document and found it a bit overwhelming, and could not figure out a way using only pd.read_csv to fix this problem.

What was the fundamental problem (I am assuming it is either user error or a problem with the file)? Is there a way to fix it with one of the commands from the read_csv?

Here is the first 2 rows from the csv file

```
cmte_id,cand_id,cand_nm,contbr_nm,contbr_city,contbr_st,contbr_zip,contbr_employer,contbr_occupation,contb_receipt_amt,contb_receipt_dt,receipt_desc,memo_cd,memo_text,form_tp,file_num,tran_id,election_tp
C00458844,"P60006723","Rubio, Marco","HEFFERNAN, MICHAEL","APO","AE","090960009","INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS","INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS",210,27-JUN-15,"","","","SA17A","1015697","SA17.796904","P2016",
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not the column that you're having a problem with, it's the index

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv', index_col=False, low_memory=False)

print(df.head(1))

     cmte_id    cand_id       cand_nm           contbr_nm contbr_city  \
0  C00458844  P60006723  Rubio, Marco  HEFFERNAN, MICHAEL         APO   

  contbr_st contbr_zip                         contbr_employer  \
0        AE  090960009  INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS   

                        contbr_occupation  contb_receipt_amt contb_receipt_dt  \
0  INFORMATION REQUESTED PER BEST EFFORTS                210        27-JUN-15   

  receipt_desc memo_cd memo_text form_tp  file_num      tran_id election_tp  
0          NaN     NaN       NaN   SA17A   1015697  SA17.796904       P2016
```

The `low_memory=False` is because column 6 has mixed datatype.

Answer (score 9):

The problem comes from having every line in the file **except for the first** terminating in a comma (the separator character). Pandas thinks there's an empty column there if it needs to consider the first 'column name' as the index column.

Try

```
data= pd.read_csv('P00000001-AL.csv',index_col=False)
```