# Read csv file using pandas and display cell value with sorted date/time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Am trying to read a csv file using pandas in the python. i have referred this link 
[pandas.read_csv moves column names over one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897414/pandas-read-csv-moves-column-names-over-one)

and used the below code to display the first row of csv file.

```
    prodid ProdParent productname    StartDate       wfStatus   ErrorMessage

    FCT   TDAR     2752_bg42328_US   3/8/2019 15:21              "PROCESs IS empty"                   
    VEE   TNL      2752_bg42329_US   3/8/2019 15:26  "success" 
    FCT   TRAD     2752_bg42328_US   3/8/2019 15:21              "PROCESs IS empty" 
    VEE   TNL      2752_bg42329_US.  3/8/2019 15:32  
    VEE   TNL      2752_bg42329_US   3/8/2019 15:34          
    VEE   TNL      2752_bg42329_US   3/8/2019 15:38    
    JUR   TLO      2755_bg567_US     4/8/2019 03:19
```

how to iterate through each n every row using pandas.
in my csv file  having a headercolumns namely errorMessage and productName, start date, wfstatus   etc...
the issue am facing is, am having some 8000 rows in my csv file and i need to filter/fetch only those rows/column values with the below conditions:

if `errorMessage_column_value == blank/null value` OR
   `wfSTATUS_columnvalue == blank/null` 
then fetch the corresponding productName cell/column value where it matches the above condition.

now, if there multiple productname column values exists with different timespan on the same date exists (in the startdate column), i need to get the latest/most recent productName value ONLY.

how to achieve this.

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_ctrl_file, index_col=False)
print(df.head(1))
```

Comment: you can use `df.loc` post input data & expected output as text into the questions so that we can help you better.

Comment: i have updated tried to explain with the actual input csv file contents and my reqmnt.. can you give me a sample of how to fetch a particular column value using df.loc . am very new to python programming.hence struggling to read and display the output

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) to find the blank rows and then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df["errorMessage"].isna() | df[" wfSTATUS_columnvalue"].isna()]
```

Comment: but, how can i iterate through each row inside csv file.is it better to use DictReader ?           with open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
 or  can i use     "" for row in reader: 
 ""

Comment: This will apply to every row, you don't need to loop. Read up on vectorization with pandas.